# why does the print command execute after the STDIN although called before it?

Tags: perl

I have a simple program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a number:\n";
my $number1 = <STDIN>;
chomp $number1;
print "Enter another number:\n";
my $number2 = <STDIN>;
chomp $number2;
if ( $number2 == 0 ) {
    print "error: cnt divide by zero\n";
}
elsif ( ( $number1 == 0 ) or ( $number2 == 1 )) {
    print "$number1\n";
}
else {
    my $div = $number1 / $number2;
    print "the result is: $div\n";
}
```

but i do not understand why the print(enter a number and enter another number is displayed after the STDIN).i get the following output

```
[612] perl test.pl
2
0
Enter a number:
Enter another number:
error:cnt divide by zero
```

Comment: [Suffering from buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)

Comment: Still, it's unusual for standard output to be buffered in an interactive program where output goes to a terminal. What OS is this?

Comment: @mob using Cygwin in windows7 professional, perl V5.8.8

Comment: @learningperl 5.8.8 is very old. Maybe you can update to some version above 5.10.1 maybe 5.14.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$| = 1` at the beginning of the program